# I have a bug "Method may fail to clean up stream or resource" in findBugs and I don't know how to solve this bug, so can someone solve it please?

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs

This method may fail to clean up (close, dispose of) a stream, database object, or other resource requiring an explicit cleanup operation.
In general, if a method opens a stream or other resource, the method should use a try/finally block to ensure that the stream or resource is cleaned up before the method returns.

This is the code:

```
public void setSource(File file) throws IOException {

 m_structure = null;
 setRetrieval(NONE);

 if (file == null) {
  throw new IOException("Source file object is null!");
 }

 try {
  setSource(new FileInputStream(file));
 } 
 catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  throw new IOException("File not found");
 }
 
 m_File = file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because of the following line:

`new FileInputStream(file)`

You could theoretically close the inputstream inside the `setSource(InputStream is)` method however that is not the correct scope. The convention is to close a stream where you opened it. So if you change your code to the following it should remove the warning. Please note that your catch block doesn't make sense since the `FileNotFoundException` is already an `IOException`. There are two possibilities:

1. Try with resources:

   ```
   public void setSource(File file) throws YourOwnApplicationException{

    if (file == null) {
     throw new YourOwnApplicationException("Source file object is null!");
    }

    try (FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file)){
     setSource(fis);
    } 
    catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
     throw new YourOwnApplicationException("File not found");
    }
   }
   ```
2. The pre Java 7/8 way:

   ```
   public void setSource(File file) throws YourOwnApplicationException {

    if (file == null) {
     throw new YourOwnApplicationException ("Source file object is null!");
    }

    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        setSource(fis);
    } 
    catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
     throw new YourOwnApplicationException("File not found");
    }
    finally {
        if(fis!=null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe) {
                //swallow
            }
        }
    }
   }
   ```

If you do it like this it also means that you have to consume your `InputStream` inside the `setSource(InputStream is)` method. Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to close it...